# Why are converter methods of Power BI visuals public instead of private?

Tags: powerbi

Working on making custom IVisual implementations; The recommended pattern includes a converter method, which converts the dataview into the visual's own view model.  I am curious why the converter is declared as public instead of private.

In the Hello World example it is [coded here](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/src/Clients/Visuals/visuals/samples/helloIVisual.ts#L77), and [explained here](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/wiki/Hello-IVisual#step-three--converter).

```
public static converter(dataView: DataView): HelloViewModel {
  ...
}
```

In code, converter seems to only be accessed within the class itself, so it is naturally a private method.  Moreover, making it public necessitates also exporting its type, HelloViewModel, which also seems to only be used internally.

**Possible answer:** There are a handful of built-in visuals that ship with their own test classes, like treemapTests.ts for treemap.ts.  These classes also test the functionality of converter methods, and this is the only place where I have seen converter called from outside of its class.

Is this the entire reason converter methods have been made public, or is there a plan to make them a formal part of the IVisual interface in the future, or is there something else going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question :) No reason. Originally there was talk to change the update options to contain the visual's vm  instead of the dataview. And power BI would use the public converter method to pass in the right vm. This way other sites hosting power bi visuals wouldn't need any dependency on dateview.  I don't think we'll be going that route though.